# How to change UI state in function that is not @Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to change text in logs in HomeUiState in function that is not @Composable?

```kotlin
data class HomeUiState(
    val logs: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(),
    ...
)

class HomeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _homeUiState = MutableStateFlow(HomeUiState())
    val homeUiState: StateFlow<HomeUiState> = _homeUiState.asStateFlow()
...

    fun appendLog(message: String){
            _homeUiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(
                    currentState.logs.append("\n$message")
                )
            }
        }
```

If I try doing like so android studio throws: "Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation" which is understandable. The appendLog is going to be invoked by the function below.

```kotlin
fun connectWithPrivateKey(
        host: String,
        username: String,
        homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
    ) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```kotlin
homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
```

in your `connectWithPrivateKey` function as this function is not a `@Composable` and it takes in a view-model which is initialized using `viewModel()` by default which is a `@Composable`.

To solve the issue, you'll have to pass a lambda function instead whole view-model to `connectWithPrivateKey` this function.

So, your `connectWithPrivateKey` function will be like

```kotlin
fun connectWithPrivateKey(
  host: String,
  username: String,
  onAppendLogs: (String) -> Unit,
) {...}
```

and you'll call `connectWithPrivateKey` like

```kotlin
connectWithPrivateKey(host = host, username = username, onAppendLogs = homeViewModel::appendLog)
```

where `homeViewModel` is initialized in your `@Composable` like

```kotlin
val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()
```